# My Function isn't working in my sql check

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to use a function inside a function but it won't work. I'm trying to send a pop up saying you have a new message after the mysql check. It shows the div when a new message comes but when pressing the x it wont go away.

```
function newmessage(){
    include ("safe.php");
    $get_pms = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `pm` WHERE `to`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND `seen`='0'") or die (mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($get_pms) > 0){
        echo "<div style='display:block;' class='alert'>
          <span class='closebtn' onclick='this.parentElement.style.display='none';'>&times;</span>
          <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<font id=\"clr\" size=\"1px\" color=\"red\"><b></b>     </font>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some Javascript or jquery to grab the id of the message (clr) and to then toggle the class to 'hidden'. It's really not too dificult but you need some basic Javascript skills.

Comment: So how would I go about this, and thanks

Comment: [mcve], please!

Comment: So how would I go about this?